# Making the spoiler markup more accessible

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, spoilers

I think we should include a faq on how to use the spoiler markup in the faq or somewhere more accessible for new users, as anime contains a lot of spoilers and many new users don't use the advanced help link when creating a question.

Just looking for a better way to inform users about the markup, otherwise this will be the main job for moderaters, implementing spoiler markup for questions by new users.

Suggestions?

Comment: To make it easy to follow, please add it as an answer to "[What should our FAQ contain?](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/10/27)" question.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just looking for a better way to inform users about the markup, otherwise this will be the main job for moderaters, implementing spoiler markup for questions by new users.

That's how it should be. Spoiler markup - which *hides information* - is by-design a *reader-hostile feature!* It should be used sparingly, and avoided whenever possible.

The last thing you want to do is encourage new users to start spoiler-marking every last detail of their posts on the off-chance that someone doesn't know them yet. This is supposed to be a community of experts and those seeking expert knowledge - don't [hide your light under a bushel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamp_under_a_bushel).

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the other answer.

Unique features for unique sites is used on sites like [math.se] for ages.

There shouldn't be much of a problem implementing it if and when the site goes live.

Comment: hopefully this is the case otherwise I'll like to see some kind of FAQ on this that we can refer new users to